# Opening File in 2 conditions

Tags: python, file

I am working on a *.txt* file. But there are 2 conditions. I do not know which one will occur. It depends on the user's decision.

My program will write what the user will make, but if there is no such a file in my program will have to create a file which its name what the user enter on the command line. Nevertheless, if there is a file my program will make all operation over this file.

So, I have tried `a+` command like `file = open(sys.argv[1],"a+")` but this did not work well. It has created a new file it didn't exist. But it did not read my file which already exists. Do you think how can I open the file that works with two conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a `try` statement. Something like:

```
try:
    # Try to open the file
    file = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
except FileNotFoundError:
    # If the file does not exist, create it
    file = open(sys.argv[1],"a+")
```